# Spring boot - Eureka - Cannot resolve entry endpoints from provided configuration

Tags: spring, spring-boot, netflix-eureka, spring-cloud-netflix

I am learning spring boot eureka for registration and discovery. Basically I have a very simple spring boot application(MyApp) that retrieves data from db and display it as json and it is working fine. Now I have created a spring boot project(eureka-server) with the following dependencies:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.0.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>eu.eureka.server</groupId>
    <artifactId>eureka-server</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>eureka-server</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring-cloud-services.version>2.1.4.RELEASE</spring-cloud-services.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>Hoxton.RC1</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
<!--        <dependency> -->
<!--            <groupId>io.pivotal.spring.cloud</groupId> -->
<!--            <artifactId>spring-cloud-services-starter-service-registry</artifactId> -->
<!--        </dependency> -->
<!--        <dependency> -->
<!--            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId> -->
<!--            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId> -->
<!--        </dependency> -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.pivotal.spring.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-services-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud-services.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

</project>
```

My application properties for the eureka-server is as follows:

```
server.port=9092
eureka.client.register-with-eureka=false

eureka.client.fetch-registry=false
```

When the project starts in order to access the eureka server dashboard I have to insert a username:user and pwd as d94653bc-e831-461c-936b-556770bf1ae0 which is generated when I start the eureka-server with command mvn spring-boot:run and i am able to login and access the dashboard:
[image]

The issue is that when i try to register my previous application(MyApp) to the eureka server with the application.properties as follows:

```
server.port=9090
 eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone=http://user:d94653bc-e831-461c-936b-556770bf1ae0:localhost:9092
```

The the application is annotated with:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableDiscoveryClient
public class MyAppApplication {
```

When i start MyApp project the following error is displayed:

```
2019-10-29 13:23:11.867 ERROR 8512 --- [  restartedMain] c.n.d.s.r.aws.ConfigClusterResolver      : Cannot resolve to any endpoints from provided configuration: {defaultZone=[http://user:d94653bc-e831-461c-936b-556770bf1ae0:localhost:9092/]}
```

If I add those two config in my application.properties  for project MyApp:

```
eureka.client.register-with-eureka=false

eureka.client.fetch-registry=false
```

No error is displayed when i start MyApp project but the project is not registered to the eureka-server dashboard.

Any idea what i am missing here please?

Please note i am running both project on my laptop.

Comment: eureka.client.register-with-eureka must be set to true

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the defaultURL is wrongly provided. Replace ":" with "@" before localhost

```
ex: http://user:d94653bc-e831-461c-936b-556770bf1ae0@localhost:9092
```